# Display .nc obtained via SentinelAPI

Tags: python, netcdf, sentinelsat

I obtained some satellite data with the `sentinelsat` package in python. I have 2 main problems:

1. I would like to plot the data I have downloaded,
2. I cannot find the documentation describing all the features available in the file I have downloaded

I downloaded the file with this function:

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt

def download():
    api = SentinelAPI('MY-USERNAME', 'MY-PASSWORD', 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')
    footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('./my.geojson'))
    products = api.query(area=footprint,
                        date=('20211019', date(2021, 12, 19)),
                        limit=1,)
    api.download_all(products)
```

I have temporarily uploaded it here for those who want to help me:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TezfAX7p5jv3pAi4gUHBn7c5OldQW7E8/view?usp=sharing

The feature list can be inspected with the following code:

```
import netCDF4

url = '.\\standard_measurement.nc'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(url)
print(nc.variables.keys())
```